# Ionic Infinite Scroll being displayed verically, Need to display it horizontally

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, scroll

I'm new to Ionic Scroll and I'm exploring a bit.
I'm not able to get the content in a horizonal row.

I've made a [pen](http://codepen.io/shaikmaqsood/full/zBbREr/  `This is the PEN`) so that we get a better idea about my issue.

[This is how I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igxyz.png)

The Images are just random images.

I tried the answers suggested for similar issues, but those aren't helping me much.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: check my answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SCREENSHOT:](http://prnt.sc/c77xku)

```
.item-complex, a.item.item-complex, button.item.item-complex {
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Yes tried your answer, But it doesn't work. I was thinking of the itesm to iterate in grid format-
  1  2  3  4
  5  6  7  8
  9  .................so on

Comment: i have sent you an screenshot where you can see that it works. You said that you want to have infinite scroll horizontally so that is what i did

Comment: Yes, That's how I want it to be...How did you do it?..The code you shared isn't doing that..Can you share the forked codepen link :)

Comment: I have updated the code so you can do that :) The code before was to create the horizontally infinite scroll

Comment: Added your Css @edisoni.1337 , But it isn't changing the view. Can you fork my pen and share the link with the changes :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works for me....:) @edisoni.1337 saves the day :) :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    .list{
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But this isn't how I was thinking of. I want it to iterate in this fashion-
  1  2  3  4
  5  6  7  8
  9  .................so on
In a grid fashion.
Sorry looks like my Question wasn't clear enough :)